# Picking up and moving objects around

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I try to find  any example in c# to pick an object into the player´s hand position and moving around. Then when the button is released, the object is dropped.I have found an example in a unity forum, but its in [javascript](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/186414/how-do-i-make-my-fps-character-grab-objects.html) , how can I implement this in C#

This is the code I found, but I need to grab it when the button is clicked and the player need to be in front of the object.

```
#pragma strict

var TheSystem : Transform;
var Distance : float;
var MaxDistance : float = 10;  

function Update() {



       var hit : RaycastHit;
     if (Physics.Raycast (TheSystem.transform.position, TheSystem.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), hit))
     {    
        if(hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "sword2"){


         Distance = hit.distance;
         if (Distance < MaxDistance){


             if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
                // show
             renderer.enabled = true;
             Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("sword2"));
                  } 

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Backspace)) {
            // hide
            renderer.enabled = false;
                 }

          }
      }
  }
  }
```

I have trid this c# example but it drag . I need to find the way to get it on the empty object when I grab in to the main camera and I need to change to grab in to an empty object inserted on the player position

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class drag : MonoBehaviour {
float distance = 10;
void OnMouseDrag(){
    Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance);
    Vector3 objPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePosition);
    transform.position = objPosition;
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt at "translating" this? And what issues did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you have in mind it is necessary to combine many things.

1. A trigger to detect when the player is next to the object
2. Read input from the player to check if he/she has pressed or released
   the button to grab the object
3. Change the position of the GameObject to be in the hand of the
   character
4. Make the grabbed GameObject child of the hand. So both move together

This script solve all the steps above. You will need to take care of adding the rigid body and collider. Also you will need to tag the object you want to collect as "item"

Extra note: If you set the collected item as child of another GameObject with a mesh, like a hand for example, the child will change its shape. So instead, use an Empty GameObject placed in the position of the hand. And pass that Empty GameObject in the inspector as a parameter for this script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class moveObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject handEmptyGameObject;
    GameObject item = null;

    bool objectOnRange = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //This is useful if you have just one item to collect in your scene
        //if you have more than one, better remove it
        item = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("item");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G) && objectOnRange)
        {
            print("Grabbing an object");
            item.transform.position = hand.transform.position;

            item.transform.SetParent(hand.transform,true);
        }
    }

    //You need to tag the GameObjec tto grab as "item" and set a 
    //collider and rigid bodies in the GameObjects
    //This is to estimate if the player is close enough to the Object

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "item")
        {
            objectOnRange = true;
            item = other.gameObject;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "item")
        {
            objectOnRange = false;
            item = other.gameObject;
        }
    }

}
```